# starting the transaction after persist in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am new to JPA and Hibernate. I was testing its transaction management last evening and noticed something. I was able to persist the entity even though I started the transaction after calling save method and also if I don't commit the transaction, its doesn't persist. I am so confused about the workflow of the hibernate transaction. Here is the code snippet:

```
 Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
 transaction = session.beginTransaction();
 firstUser  = createUser("aaa@aa.com", "a", "yyy", true);
 session.save(firstUser);
 session.beginTransaction().commit();
```

I have expected it not to be saved or throw exception as I saved the entry before starting the transaction.

Comment: Why are you using session.beginTransaction() in 2nd line and at the time of commit?

Comment: You are using Hibernate api, not JPA, which has very different contracts. JPA's method would not allow this, and make it more clear - offering only getTransaction and an exception if you try to call begin on an active transaction. And JPA would cause your session (entityManager) to join to the active transaction, so commit will pick up all changes within the EntityManager when it is called. JPA delays flushing changes until commit by default, so persist doesn't really do anything until a flush/commit call anyway (provider and option specific)

Answer (score 0):

> I have expected it not to be saved or throw exception as I saved the entry before starting the transaction.

You started a new transaction with the first call of `beginTransaction`. Then you saved the entity. Then you called `beginTransaction` again. This will just return the current transaction without starting a new one. Then you committed the transaction and the entity has been persisted.

It works as expected and as described in Javadoc: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/SharedSessionContract.html#beginTransaction()